# CommandNotFoundException running AZ modules from a Hybrid worker

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a Hybrid worker VM configured on my Azure Automation Account runbook and I am trying to invoke some Pester scripts(ps1 file with invoke-pester command kept in the Hybrid worker VM) from there as an elevated session(with start-process `-runas` verb which invokes the ps1 in the VM). But when I do so the pester scripts to give this exception.

> CommandNotFoundException: The 'New-AzStorageContext' command was found
>
> in the module 'Az.Storage', but the module could not be loaded. For
>   more
>
> information, run 'Import-Module Az.Storage'.

I am importing the AZ module before the Invoke pester command(Az is latest 1.6.0, Powershell and .net are all latest versions). Still, it does not do anything. I tried to edit the Allusers/AllHosts profile (added Import-Module AZ) in the Hybrid worker VM and ran the runbook. It rectifies the issue for one run, and again I get the issue (it removes the Import-Module AZ added by me and resets itself in the windowspowershell V1.0 directory)), the reason is weirdly the `profile.ps1` resets itself.

Expected: Autoimports AZ modules
Actual: Does not autoimport AZ modules

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened recently with one VSTS Windows Agent-hybrid Worker, some of the guys installed a new version module az.keyvaults and it was failing with the same error, I found the offending modules in this path:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell, after I deleted the az.keyvaults module started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The Az module was installed on the VM but the Hybrid Worker returned error that `The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Then I discovered the problem. I installed the Az module like this:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

See the **-Scope** parameter. The Az module was installed only for me. You have to change it to **AllUsers** and your hybrid worker will work.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope AllUsers -Repository PSGallery -Force
```